# How can I create the necessary out-directories for targets with make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say, in a `Makefile`, I have the following targets:

```
EXES=dir1/subdir1/abc dir1/subdir1/def dir1/subdir2/ghi dir1/subdir2/jkl dir2/subdir3/mno dir2/subdir3/pqr
```

Each item in `$(EXES)` represents a binary to be created. I want to make sure that the necessary directories (in the example: `dir1/subdir1`, `dir1/subdir2`, `dir2/subdir3`) are created if they are not existent.

How would I achieve this with gnu-make?

Answer (score 1):

Use order-only prerequisites:

```
target: prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites

order-only-prerequisites:
    recipe
```

Their recipe is executed only if they do not exist yet. Example:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/foo.o: src/foo.c | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

And if you want to extract the list of directories to create from the definition of your `EXES` variable:

```
$(EXES): | $(dir $(EXES))

$(dir $(EXES)):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Or, to instantiate exactly one rule per target:

```
define DIR_rule
$(1): | $$(dir $(1))
endef
$(foreach e,$(EXES),$(eval $(call DIR_rule,$(e))))

$(dir $(EXES)):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: This assumes that there are no subdirectories in `$(BUILDDIR)`.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: I do not understand. What would it change if they were subdirectories in `$(BUILDDIR)`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Oh! I see from your own answer that you wanted to extract the directories from the `EXES` definition. I added this to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution with `$(dir ...)`

```
EXE_DIRS=$(dir $(EXES))

EXE_DIRS_UNIQUE=$(shell for DIR in $(EXE_DIRS); do echo $$DIR; done | sort | uniq)

$(shell for DIR in $(EXE_DIRS_UNIQUE); do if [ ! -d $$DIR ]; then mkdir -p $$DIR; fi; done)

all: $(EXES)
```

Comment: Try not to use `$(shell )` in your makefiles. Use _make_ instead. Here for instance you run a for loop even when everything is already up-to-date. @Renaud's solution is the way to go. It will even do everything in parallel when you use `-j`